# POJO fields disappearing when passed to client from endpoint

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have a POJO that I'm using to pass some data that I've retrieved from a query from teh datastore:

```
public class User {
    public String email;
    public String username;
}
```

I set the data from the datastore query, and check that it's set right on the server side.

Then it is bundled into a CollectionResponse and returned from the endpoint to the Android client. Then the data is extracted.

The problem is that when it arrives on the client, `email` is set to `null`. The `username` field still has its data though.

I've tried it with getters and setters defined, with `ApiResourceProperty` set, but it doesn't help. The weird thing is that I have a very similar setup with another endpoint and there it all works no problem.

Anyone know why this could happen?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that in your endpoint method you specify an HTTPMethod of "Post". 
Example:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "setAnimals", path = "animals", httpMethod = "POST")
public AnimalResponse setAnimal(Animal animal) {}
```